# PHP Library in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

I want to use a library(http://geocoder-php.org/Geocoder/) maintained by composer in my wordpress plugin. I am not using composer in wordpress so I am wondering how can I use such library, install its dependencies and auto load in a call back function. I tried to include files manually but it seems i will have to include many files in correct order which seems impossible. Is there a workaround? Here is my code.

```
function cdsf_plugin_menu_content() {

    require_once( MYPATH . '/Ivory/HttpAdapter/PsrHttpAdapterInterface.php' );
    require_once( MYPATH . '/Ivory/HttpAdapter/HttpAdapterInterface.php' );
    require_once( MYPATH . '/Ivory/HttpAdapter/AbstractHttpAdapter.php' );
    require_once( MYPATH . '/Ivory/HttpAdapter/AbstractCurlHttpAdapter.php' );
    require_once( MYPATH . '/Ivory/HttpAdapter/CurlHttpAdapter.php' );
    require_once( MYPATH . '/Geocoder/Geocoder.php' );
    require_once( MYPATH . '/Geocoder/ProviderAggregator.php' );
    require_once( MYPATH . '/Geocoder/TimedGeocoder.php' );
    $curl     = new \Ivory\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();
    $geocoder = new \Geocoder\Provider\GooglMaps($curl);
    ....
}
```

Comment: You can install something using Composer but there's no requirement to continue using it. Just do the normal `composer install xyz` and then `require_once` the `autoload.php` file. Or if you want, investigate the contents of the folder `vendor/composer`, specifically the `autoload_classmap.php` file probably.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks. Make it answer so that i can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install something using Composer but there's no requirement to continue using it. Just do the normal `composer install xyz` and then `require_once` the `autoload.php` file. Or if you want, investigate the contents of the folder `vendor/composer`, specifically the `autoload_classmap.php` file probably.